# Using Workflow to set Task Outcome column value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, tasks, task-list, choice-field

I am trying to create a workflow that will change the "Task Outcome" value of a task.  The task list is associated with an Approval Workflow and was created when the specific instance of the approval workflow was configured.  I can change other columns (such as "% complete" and "status") no problem but the "Task Outcome" refuses to change.  I am wondering if it has to do with the fact that the Type is "Outcome Choice" rather than "Choice".  Has anyone done this?

I am using a Sharepoint 2010 workflow in SPD 2013.

Comment: If I create a new Tasks List, I don't see the "Task Outcome" choice field. But I do see "Priority" and "Task Status" choice types. Is the Task Outcome a custom Site/List Column or are you using a different SP-version than me (who uses SPO)?

Comment: Maybe I should add that the tasks list is to do with an approval workflow.  The task list was created when I established the approval workflow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm now told over at MSDN that this is not possible OOTB.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/511f5495-07af-457c-aa8b-bc45910cdcf1/using-spd-workflow-to-set-approval-workflow-task-outcome?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Should you add the Ref please  ?